# How to prove combinatorics product rule using sum rule with induction

Tags: combinatorics, induction

I apologize I don't know latex

So I'm trying to use induction and the sum rule to prove that if we assume $P(k)$ where the statement is that there are $r_1 \cdot r_2 \cdot r_3 \cdot \dots r_k$ steps to complete a certain operation. However, I'm not sure what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, you want to prove $p_0:=1,\,p_{k+1}:=p_kr_{k+1}$ implies $p_k=\prod_{j=1}^kr_j$. The inductive step would use multiplication. What "sum rule" do you intend?

Comment: correct, so I'm assuming the base case should be P(1)? but I don't even know what would be in this case. The sum rule I mean is $ |A| = \sum_{i=1}^k |Bm| = |B1| + |B2| +... +|Bk| $

Comment: It depends on what you mean by the product rule. If you are referring to the cardinality of a Cartesian product, it's easy. Do it for the Cartesian product of two finite sets by fixing the first entry and using the sum rule, and use induction to generalize it. However, there is a more general variation of the product rule where you are looking at a certain symmetric subsets of a Cartesian product. In that case, the challenge is defining such subsets, after which it is a matter of induction again. I think what you need to do here is make it clearer what you mean by "operation".